# How to get the current row of a QML TreeView?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols

Is there a way to get the row number of a QML `TreeView` when selecting/clicking something on the `TreeView`? For example, for a `TableView` I use `currentRow`. Is there something equivalent for a `TreeView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `currentIndex`. More info in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-treeview.html#currentIndex-prop).

For example:

```
TreeView {
    id: myTree
    ...
    model: myModel

    onCurrentIndexChanged: console.log("current index: " + currentIndex
                                       + " current row: " + currentIndex.row)

    TableViewColumn {
        title: "title1"
        role: "role1"
    }

    TableViewColumn {
        title: "title2"
        role: "role2"
    }

    onClicked: {
        console.log("clicked", index)
    }
}
```

You can check [the complete example](https://github.com/ftena/qml-c/tree/master/file-browser) in GitHub.